# Check for required in angular HTML

Tags: angular

In my form I'm trying to check for  if the the control is required in the HTML so I can show error text.
How do I do this? `.required` is not valid.

```
<span *ngIf="profileForm.controls.firstName.required">This is required</span>
```

```
export class LoginFormComponent {
  profileForm = new FormGroup({
    firstName: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks that got me to what I needed to look for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Small improvement on @Hello-World's answer:

```html
<div *ngIf="profileForm.controls.firstName.errors?.['required']">
    Name is required.
</div>
```

You can use the `Optional chaining` `?` to check if the property is available.

Check the documentation for more information: https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#validating-input-in-reactive-forms

Answer (score 0):

```
<span *ngIf="profileForm.controls.firstName.errors && profileForm.controls.firstName.errors['required']">(required.)</span>
```

Here is the solution that I used.